# string to double conversion in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i tried assigning values like this ,where coffeshop is an object with latitude a string variable,however value of coordinates are shown 0 values,while i nslog the coffeeshop.latitude and longitude i am getting correct values,is there any error in this conversion

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
 coordinate.latitude=[coffeeshop.latitude doubleValue];
 coordinate.longitude=[coffeeshop.latitude doubleValue];
```

Comment: is the string purely the number? with no extra characters

Comment: To reinforce DJ Bouche's point, latitudes and longitudes need not be written down as strings that can be converted by `-doubleValue` for example N 55 10' 21" is one way to write a latitude and it will return 0 if sent `-doubleValue` thanks to the N at the front.

Comment: it is purely the number only....however i tried with NSScanner and it is working now...NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:coffeeshop.latitude];
 
double anlat;
 
[aScanner scanDouble:&anlat];CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
   coordinate.latitude=anlat; this is lot more code than what i did earlier but works fine

Answer (score 1):

Hello
I sure it's a culture problem
you must check your string format
I got the same error cause my String contraint **coma** separator instead of **point**. 
try to replace "**,**" for "**.**" (something like this) in the string